# Problems with CSS rotateY and links

Tags: css

please try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bananajo/W6s8H/11/)

I have problems with not working links links on the backside.

Can anyone help?

It works with FF but in Crome it does not work.

This is the page where i have the idea from http://www.asuum.com

```
$("a.image").live({
    mouseenter: function(event){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        console.log('hier');

        $flipbox = $('#li_'+id).find('.flipbox');
        $front = $flipbox.find('.front');
        $back = $flipbox.find('.back');

        $('#event_button_'+id).hide();

        $back.show();
        $flipbox.addClass('turnover');
        return false;
    }  
});
```

Comment: I don't see any difference in FF and Chrome. You should discribe better what does not work, what is the expected behaviour and what is the actual behaviour.

Comment: when you enter the image with the mouse, the links on the left side does not work.. but on the right side the links are working.. the links are just clickable untill the center. but this problem is just in Crome.. in FF all links are working

Comment: it is working!! t hink it was just da cache problem :/

Answer (score 1):

change `-webkit-transform: rotateY(181deg);` at 180 and less it is ,kind of ,not rotated fully and a half of object is missing

```
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(181deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6s8H/17/)